# How to store very small numbers in Python?

Tags: python, variables

When the number is extremely small, it's expressed as 0.0 in default python data types (float, int). I tried using float instead of int, but it still doesn't store very small numbers effectively. Is there another way for a variable to store numbers, possibly even smaller than e-308? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked the [decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) library? That may suit your purpose

Comment: "even smaller than e-308" -- I'm curious, what would be the usecase? (Perhaps you ought to change the units?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use decimal.

```
from decimal import Decimal

number = Decimal('0.00000000000000000000000000000001')

print(number)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wV7xQ.png)